# Find and replace a sub sub array element in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, multidimensional-array

Hi I am developing MeteorJS app, I am stuck at updating a sub sub array element.

It is a poll application and I have the following database structure:

Under each question there are options and when a user clicks a button of an option, I want to increment that options votes by one and every user should have one vote right for each question.

From the button, I am passing name and questionId data in order to find the right option to increment vote. I should find the specific question with the questionId and then the specific array with the name under the Options.

Where I am stuck at is I can't find it.

Please help, thanks

Collection Name: Polls

Each Poll has the following structure:

```js
{
    "_id" : "uJtBt8mM2pbTYfwND",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-04-03T22:40:14.678Z"),
    "pollName" : "First Poll",
    "entryOwner" : "gdAHxDrxFuTvYiFt8",
    "question" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Question number 1",
            "questionId" : "xgYQxGxpwBXaQpjXN",
            "options" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "John",
                    "votes" : 0
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "Adam",
                    "votes" : 0
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "Robert",
                    "votes" : 0
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Question number 2",
            "questionId" : "zviwYHHsaATBdG6Jw",
            "options" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "John",
                    "votes" : 0
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "Adam",
                    "votes" : 0
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "Robert",
                    "votes" : 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $and which performs a logical AND operation on an array of two or more expressions.

```
{ $and: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> } , ... , { <expressionN> } ] }
```

The first expression here would be to get the question with questionId.

```
'question.questionId': "xgYQxGxpwBXaQpjXN"
```

And second expression to specify the object with matching name in options array.
To find the object with the name in options array, you can use $elemMatch which allows to specify queries.

```
{ <field>: { $elemMatch: { <query1>, <query2>, ... } } }
```

To get the object in options array having name as "John".

```
'question.options': {
    $elemMatch: {
        name: "John"
    }
}
```

And finally, use $inc to increase the votes (here by 1).
It will get the first matching element (with $).

```
'question.options.$.votes': 1
```

Here's the full code:

```
db.Polls.update({
    $and: [{
            'question.questionId': "xgYQxGxpwBXaQpjXN"
        },
        {
            'question.options': {
                $elemMatch: {
                    name: "John"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}, {
    $inc: {
        'question.options.$.votes': 1
    }
})
```

Comment: In Stack Overflow, it's not enough to write code. Please annotate and explain the code.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation, the problem is that when running this code it does not know the question's index therefore it can not update the votes. I have solved this by installing underscore.js library and finding each items index when the button is clicked.